# I am getting 5 errors in my "hello world" C++ program

Tags: c++

My code is...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

The errors i am getting are...

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved  main.cpp    /First/src  line 3  Semantic Error
Program "g++" not found in PATH First       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Program "gcc" not found in PATH First       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved main.cpp    /First/src  line 8  Semantic Error
Program "make" not found in PATH    First           C/C++ Problem
```

Does anybody know whats wrong? This is my first time trying C++ and i am using eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64

Comment: The errors you are getting have nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Either you don't have a compiler installed, or your IDE (Eclipse) isn't configured to use the compiler that you do have installed.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment yet but based on the error messages it seems that the compiler has not been setup properly or Eclipse cannot find it.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/238347/

Make sure Eclipse can find your compiler.

You may have to setup some environment variables.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Also try following the instruction in the error message.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

install g++ in your system and set env path!

Answer (score 0):

In my case on osx, the errors on the basic hello world project were caused by something silly. everything was installed but i had no clue that the gcc expected me to read and agree to a License. go to terminal and type $ gcc. i was then prompted with the need to deal with the license agreement. once that was done, eclipse build the hello world project without problem. hope this helps others ...

Comment: For the record, that is nothing to do with gcc, it's the fake gcc that Apple install (it's really a version of clang). So that is  not going to be the problem for someone using Windows.